# How do you emulate a right click on a tablet/mobile device using OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to make my OpenLayers mapping application work for mobile devices and one feature I haven't figured out how to emulate is the 'handleRightClicks'  Control Click option.  Anyone know how to make this work with tablets/mobile devices?

Comment: It's not possible to trigger rightclick on tablets/mobile devices so you are not able to test and you don't even need to test that functionalities unless you set the functionalities on other event type.